# Replicating the Slinging Effect in Google+'s Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm working on a simple application but I'm a bit of a space freak. I noticed that Google+ uses quite a interesting approach to do this in their mobile approach. I'm just curious about how would one go about implementing something like that.

Disclaimer: I'm typically a C++ programmer, but I'm trying my hand into Java development for Android. Any and all kinds of help are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "slinging effect" you are referring to is that done by a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Here is a helpful [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) to get you started.

To implement your `ViewPager` with titles, you'll need to use a third party library, as Android does not implement this functionality by default. I would recommend using Jake Wharton's [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library. It's easy to use and well-maintained.

Comment: I most definitely should have RTFM myself. Thanks @Alex Lockwood.